# Troubles using CGPathContainsPoint SWIFT

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, cgpath

I need to check if a CGPoint is inside a SKSpriteNode.

After a little research, CGPathContainsPoint seems appropriated for my purpose.

```
if CGPathContainsPoint(my_sprite_path, nil, my_point, false) {

 }
```

But Xcode alerts me: *Use of unresolved identifier CGPathContainsPoint*

I tried to import :

```
import UIKit
import CoreGraphics
```

I'm using Xcode 8.0 beta 6.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Have you tried restarting Xcode just to make sure core graphics was imported correct?  The usage looks fine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As of Swift 3, many Core Graphics functions are now *methods*
on the corresponding type. In your example:

```
if my_sprite_path.contains(my_point) {

}
```

For more information see
[SE-044 Import as member](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0044-import-as-member.md).

Comment: Thanks it works. Usually Xcode suggests the new methods in Swift 3. I don't understand why for this one, not :)